# Outlook.Application & ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, outlook, activex

Всем привет! Подскажите - в IE использую ActiveXObject для получения вложений из открытого почтовика Outlook 2016. Получение реквизитов письма, заголовков, вложений, названий вложений - работает.

```
`$(function(){
var app = new ActiveXObject('Outlook.Application')
var ex = app.ActiveExplorer()
var sel = ex.Selection()
var mail = sel.Item(1)
alert(mail.Attachments.count);
//Вот тут работает
mail.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile('C:\123\'+mail.Attachments(1).FileName)
//Папка пустая
});`
```

---

В чем может быть проблема?
Рассчитываю на Вашу поддержку!

Comment: Но при этом ошибок не выдается!

Comment: Возможно \ нужно экранировать двумя \\ при указании пути (т.е. `C:\\123\\`)

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!